# Add a new field for already existing resource using PUT

Tags: mongodb, api, next.js

I implemented google auth in my NextJS app. The idea is: user makes some progress working with my web app, I store this progress in local storage as an array. If he decides to register I receive the session back, then I send `PUT` request to db to update the document by inserting a new field (array) from local storage.

I implemented `GET` request that returns registered user data by `email` and it works. The question is, how to insert a new field using `PUT` method? In my case this field is `array` and calls `progress`. I'm not sure if I should use `update`.

This is the record from my mongodb:

```
_id: 63cc85641624a77f17ca5f29
name: "John P"
email: "john.p@gmail.com"
image: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp7xzF4eYtyhTgRxmgP4vYdCqDa6zW…"
emailVerified: null
```

I want to add a new field: `progress: ['some data']`

This is my PUT request:

```
      case 'PUT':
        const updateData = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/updateOne`, {
          ...fetchOptions,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            ...fetchBody,
            filter: { email: email },
            update: {}   <---------------!!!!!
          }),
        })
        const updateDataJson = await updateData.json()
        res.status(200).json(updateDataJson.documents)
        break
```

Comment: Can you post the code handling the `/updateOne` end-point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your document using `updateOne`, and add a `progress` key, you can use:

```
filter: { email: email },
update: {$set: {progress: arr}}
```